# Next JS - Persisting Data Across Postback Requests

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-props

So I've got a bit of an odd specification that I'm trying to get my head around, and I'm hoping somebody on here can point me in the right direction, or tell me if what I'm attempting is even viable.

Essentially, I have to use Next JS to build a multi-stage form (using proceed/cancel buttons). It sounds incredibly simple, and is when you can do it all client-side, but I've had it specified that I will need to use Server-Side Rendering and page refreshes to accommodate old browsers that can't rely on Javascript.

I've been able to get the proceed/cancel functionality by placing a value in the query string, and passing this in through `props` to render the appropriate page. (I'm relatively new to Next, so I don't know if this is the optimum approach for what I'm trying to do)

This leaves me in a position where I am struggling to persist the data that is entered at each stage of the form, as it appears to be obliterated on each navigation to the next step. This means that no data can be submitted at the end of the form, and even if you were to go forward and then back, the data that was entered will no longer exist.

I've put together a little sandbox app to tinker with the idea, and here's a look at what I think my `index.js` should look like:

```
const App = ({formStep}) => {
  return (
    <>
      {formStep == 0 && (
        <FirstInfoBlock />
      )}
      {formStep == 1 && (
        <SecondInfoBlock />
      )}
      {formStep == 2 && (
        <ThirdInfoBlock />
      )}
    </>
  )
}

  export default App;

  export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    return {
      props: {
        formStep: context.query.formStep ? parseInt(context.query.step) : 0, //this is working as expected
        formData: {
          //this is what I would like to populate with each step of the form, but does not persist through postback
          firstInfo: ??
          secondInfo: ??
          thirdInfo: ??
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

So that is where I am currently. I was hoping there is a way to use the navigation to `Post` back to the same URL with the data from whichever components being passed in the request body, but I do not know how to do this while navigating the form.

I understand that this probably isn't what Next JS is ideally used for, but please bear in mind that this is the task I've been given and it is in a framework that certainly isn't my strong point.

If anyone can shed any light on how I might be able to accomplish what I'm trying to do, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't know if I understand your requirements correctly, but ```getServerSideProps``` only runs on the server-side, so the only way to persist the data is to store it temporarily in some DB (Redis for example), and then fetch it directly inside  ```getServerSideProps```

Comment: I am not sure what the limit is, age/year wise, to accommodate old browsers but I'd use `sessionStorage` or even `localStorage`. It is supported by all browsers and even older ones.